# How do I see why a Jenkins build failed?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create my first Jenkins build job on a new Jenkins server. On the first two attempts the job failed; after I fixed those problems, the next build (which I requested manually by clicking "build now") failed - but there was no build error given.

The only useful information I see is "No changes" (and a mercurial revision ID) on the build status page.

How can I see why the build failed?

Comment: You should either modify this question and answer to be something search able with a clear problem description and answer or just delete it.  As it stands now it's unlikely to help future folks, which is the overall goal of this site.

Comment: I didn't check what it used to be, but as it is now I find this incredibly useful. My Google search led me to it immediately. Someans , that probably congratulations on an effective edit!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Never mind. I needed to click on the "Console output" link on the left.

Comment: Most Jenkins problems require reading the console output.  Only a handful of possible problems are digested and presented on the summary pages.

Comment: @EdwinBuck - how can we get the summary(cause of failure) on the build status page `host:port/job/xyzJob/4/`?

Comment: It can be nice for Jenkins at least to show some summary with errors, as it's really counterintuitive to click on "console output" and then you need to scroll to the bottom of all logs... Well, at least you've got some reputation beause of such implementation ;)

Comment: I have not tried it yet but there is a Build Failure analyzer plugin you can get from Git. It is an AI based system where you can put in resolutions as you fix things to help it get better it helping you resolve issues.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the **project page** and Click on the failed build number from the **'Build History'**.

- Click on the 'Console Output',
  [Console Output gives the details like line by line build execution sequence with time 
  stamp,Build Success messages, Build Failure messgaes, File location details at which 
  ERROR has occured, ERROR details etc..,]
- Look for the details: File at which the ERROR has occured, ERROR details.

  **You can still investigate...**
- Click 'Back to Project'
- Then Click **Workspace** on the left and go to the specified file location.
  Ex: data-mart-db/target/
  [You can find log files below the actual code files.]
- Open the log files one by one and go to the end of file(ctrl+end).
  Error details will be displayed, if the error has occured in that file.

  **Fix the ERRORs in the local setup first & then do the checkins to the repository again**.

  Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that there is console output for the project too, which does not contain any useful information, but there may be separate configuration (by default `default`), which contains the console log that contains actual execution.